# How to re-enable photo uploading for Twitter

Tags: help, html5

When attempting to upload a profile photo to Twitter, I inadvertently selected an option from a notification from the Tor browser that stopped my ability to upload photos from my personal computer to Twitter (it said that by uploading the photo, my computer would be at risk of being identified). Now when I try to to upload a profile photo, the space appears blank. How to I get back to the options on Tor to allow the browser to upload pictures from my computer to Twitter?

Comment: Okay, I found this two years later and am having the same problem ie. I go through the *upload image* process and end up with a blank image. Looking at the solution given it's not clear what you mean by "Allow in future". Where is this an option that I can choose?

Comment: There is an option right now for this :
"Allow data access" right before the url tab.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter uses a `<canvas>` object to allow the user to trim/resize their avatar.

Tor Browser will by default block this because it can be misused to fingerprint users.

The easiest way to get the prompt back will be to restart Tor Browser or use the New Identity button and restart the process of uploading a new avatar, note that by the time Twitter prompts you about it you may already need to go back to the start of uploading a new avatar because the prompt comes up after it's made the attempt to read the `<canvas>`.

Restart Tor Browser -> Login to Twitter -> Upload image -> Choose "Allow in Future" -> Upload image *again* -> Done

Comment: This answer is not helping as stated above. Where to enable "Allow in Future"? It is not possible to upload pics on Twitter, very annoying because there is no solution anywhere to find. Please help, thanks.