# Uploading a twitter header in Tor Browser

Tags: help

I'm trying to upload a twitter header using the Tor browser and I seem to go through the process okay but at the end I'm told I was successful but my header is blank.

The steps I take are:

1) Go to profile

2) Click "Edit Profile"

3) Click "Change your header photo"

4) Select "Upload Photo" from the drop-down

5) Select the image I want uploaded

6) Click "Apply"

The "Your header was published successfully" message appears but the image is not there. And when I select "Save Changes" it remains blank.

I've seen another post about this problem from 2017 ([Similar Problem](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14260/how-to-re-enable-photo-uploading-for-twitter)) that suggests the following steps:

Restart Tor Browser -> Login to Twitter -> Upload image -> Choose "Allow in Future" -> Upload image again -> Done

But I don't see any "Allow in Future" option so am stuck. Does anyone know where this option is or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted the same and received with the same result with the normal and mobile versions and with and without NoScript.

This looks to be a bug, on the side of Twitter or Tor Browser, I can't tell. It is possible that twitter is just not allowing this to happen when you connect via Tor.